# What is the convention for writing Matlab code: CamelCase or snake_case

Tags: matlab, camelcasing

What is the convention for writing Matlab code as used in built-in matlab functions and major toolboxes: [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) or [snake_case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)?

Comment: It's completely subjective, but looking at MathWorks code, I'd say neither.  However, the error message IDs are generally written in CamelCase.

Comment: It's whatever your MATLAB coding guidelines say.

Comment: I prefer to use lower case for MATLAB programming to „turn off“ case sensitivity (coding rules: http://goo.gl/TfVX9E).

Comment: See also this question and answers: [MATLAB programming best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042761/matlab-programming-best-practices/5050674). Richard K. Johnson's book ["The Elements of MATLAB Style"](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0521732581) may have something to say on this. One thing that I've seen is that Classes tend to use upper camel case (e.g., `VideoWriter`) and methods of objects use lower camel case. (e.g., `writeVideo`).